# Unable to open my storyboard in another mac Xcode8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I am unable to open my Xcode project's storyboard on another mac. All I did was copy the whole folder and paste it in another mac. I am unable to open the storyboard but I am able to view the code. When I click on the storyboard nothing happens.

I have tried to open the storyboard as source code but there was no options at all. This happened to me twice and I am not sure why.

[This is the screenshot of my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXoqS.png)
[The storyboard shows that it is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi7Uu.png)

Comment: Do you have the same Xcode version? If the storyboard was created on Xcode 8 and you are trying to open with Xcode 7, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: yes, both version are the same

Comment: Can you post a screenshot how it looks on your project folder after your copy it?

Comment: I mean, you can open your workspace file right? so after you open, attach a screenshot of your project navigator. Sorry for the miss lead

Comment: yes i can open the workspace, its just that my storyboard cant load. When i click on my view controllers, the codes appear but when i click on storyboard, nothing happens.